# Rails “field-with-errors” get parent node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have some haml like this

```
= form_for [:admin, @school] do |f|
  [...]
  = f.fields_for :address do |a|
    [...]
    .col-md-3
      .form-group.form-md-line-input.form-md-floating-label
        = a.text_field :postal_code, id: 'form_3', class: 'form-control'
        %label{:for => "form_3"} Postleitzahl
```

that renders to

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
    <input id="form_3" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="school[address_attributes][postal_code]">
    <label for="form_3">Postleitzahl</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

When there is an error, the code should be like

```
[...]
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label has-error">
[...]
```

To solve this:
Is there a way to select the parent node within config/initializers/field_error_proc.rb?

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
```

--> Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_tag).parent returns nil.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more context from your view?

Comment: What do you need more?

Comment: In your view, can you show me a little bit more about the form itself, e.g. form_for, etc.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't parse YAML, it parses XML and HTML. If you'd like to show us the HTML being generated then we can help you. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @theTinMan I fail to see where the YAML is.  All I see is HAML/Slim, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It's a typo. HAML != HTML, unless it's been rendered. The OP needs to show the rendered output as that's what Nokogiri would need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, I'm going off of memory right now, but this should help.

The `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc` is terrible.  Don't use it.  I say this because it's extremely unpredictable to someone who doesn't understand what it's supposed to do (e.g. if you didn't know what it was, you wouldn't understand why these `div`s suddenly appeared around your fields, and mess up your styling).  Plus, it's not what you need.

So, this is what you do.  Since you're using HAML/Slim, you can't conditionally add a single class.  So, you're going to have to encapsulate the entire thing in an `if` statement, which is fine.  You can check for errors using [`#errors`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-errors):

```
.col-md-3
  - if @school.errors[:postal_code].any?
    .form-group.form-md-line-input.form-md-floating-label.has-error
      - # ...
   - else
    .form-group.form-md-line-input.form-md-floating-label
       - # ...
```

The `@school.errors[:postal_code].any?` checks to see if there are any validation errors associated with the `:postal_code` field.  It returns true if there are, so we create a div with the proper classes in response.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent node of

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label has-error">
```

Try:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
    <input id="form_3" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="school[address_attributes][postal_code]">
    <label for="form_3">Postleitzahl</label>
  </div>
</div>
EOT

div = doc.at('[class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label"]') 
# => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff0e0c14d80 name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c14ac4 name="class" value="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff0e0c141dc "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff0e0c14060 name="input" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c1422c name="id" value="form_3">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c14560 name="class" value="form-control">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c14740 name="type" value="text">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c147b8 name="value">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c148d0 name="name" value="school[address_attributes][postal_code]">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff0e0c054e8 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff0e0c053d0 name="label" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff0e0c052f4 name="for" value="form_3">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff0e0c04b74 "Postleitzahl">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff0e0c0487c "\n  ">]>

div.parent.to_html 
# => "<div class=\"col-md-3\">\n  <div class=\"form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label\">\n    <input id=\"form_3\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" name=\"school[address_attributes][postal_code]\">\n    <label for=\"form_3\">Postleitzahl</label>\n  </div>\n</div>"
```

Normally, if we know we want a particular class, we can use shorthand to locate the nodes that use it:

```
doc.at('.form-group') 
# => #(Element:0x3fec6acbc8d4 {
#      name = "div",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x3fec6acbc0dc {
#          name = "class",
#          value = "form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label"
#          })],
#      children = [
#        #(Text "\n    "),
#        #(Element:0x3fec6aca83ac {
#          name = "input",
#          attributes = [
#            #(Attr:0x3fec6accdea4 { name = "id", value = "form_3" }),
#            #(Attr:0x3fec6accde90 { name = "class", value = "form-control" }),
#            #(Attr:0x3fec6accde7c { name = "type", value = "text" }),
#            #(Attr:0x3fec6accde54 { name = "value", value = "" }),
#            #(Attr:0x3fec6accde2c {
#              name = "name",
#              value = "school[address_attributes][postal_code]"
#              })]
#          }),
#        #(Text "\n    "),
#        #(Element:0x3fec6acdce04 {
#          name = "label",
#          attributes = [
#            #(Attr:0x3fec6acdc9cc { name = "for", value = "form_3" })],
#          children = [ #(Text "Postleitzahl")]
#          }),
#        #(Text "\n  ")]
#      })
```

This breaks down when we want to use multiple classes:

```
doc.at('.form-group form-md-line-input') 
# => nil
```

But the form I used above using `[class="..."]` will work.

Comment: Okay, cool! But in my context I am struggeling with the variable html_tag. I can't find a way to select the parent element, because it only contains the input.